# Function doesn't see variable in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Here I've got an error: `"ReferenceError: z is not defined at func`:

```
const func = (x) => x + z;
const func2 = (z) => func;
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

I understand that I can write it like this:

```
const func2 = (z) => (x) => x + z;
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

But I add documentation comments using JSDoc for each function and this way looks better for me:

```
/**
 * @param {string|number} x
 * @returns {string} 
 */
const func = (x) => x + z;
/**
 * @param {number} z
 * @returns {Function} 
 */
const func2 = (z) => func;
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

Instead of:

```
/**
 * @param {number} z
 * @returns {Function} 
 */
const func2 = (z) => {
  /**
   * @param {string|number} x
   * @returns {string} 
   */
  return (x) => x + z;
};
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

I can be wrong but what way is the best to solve my problem?

Comment: Javascript has *lexical* scope, not dynamic. Your `func2` accepts an argument `z` but it doesn't pass it on to `func`, hence it's not defined there. You either have to write the definition nested, or explicitly pass on the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because

```
const func = (x) => x + z;
```

tries to use `z`, which isn't in scope for it.

`func` will still need to be defined within `func2` so it has access to `z`. You could use the verbose form so you can create the `const` and associate doc comments with it:

```
/**
 * @param {number} z
 * @returns {Function} 
 */
const func2 = (z) => {
    /**
     * @param {string|number} x
     * @returns {string} 
     */
    const func = (x) => x + z;
    return func;
};
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

...although JSDoc *may* even be smart enough to pick them up in the concise form:

```
/**
 * @param {number} z
 * @returns {Function} 
 */
const func2 = (z) =>
    /**
     * @param {string|number} x
     * @returns {string} 
     */
    (x) => x + z
;
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't created a closure.

Scope is determined by where a function is **defined**, not where it is called.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
const func = function (x) { return x + z ).bind(this);
const func2 = function (z) { return func() }.bind(this);
```

You have to define one function inside the other to create a closure and maintain access to the scope.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a real closure, which returns a function with scope over `z`.

```js
const func2 = z => x => x + z;
const a = func2(1);
const b = a(2);

console.log(a)
console.log(b);
```

Comment: How does he comment it, though?